# Xamarin error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 2. 0

Tags: java, xamarin

My app is unchanged from yesterday when it compiled. I turned Multi-Dex on (it wasn't). What does this error mean?

Comment: Enable diagnostic level logging for msbuild and get the full error stack for this build task.

Comment: Where is your android sdk located?

Comment: Before it compiled, what been done with project?This need more error info.

Comment: I'm trying a new approach: Since this error is a new thing I'm recreating my app in a new folder. So far, I have not gotten this error. I figured, yes, it could be due to some misconfigured something but I'd rather get the app going and move on, if that's possible.

Comment: @Ron If solved problem, remember to post it as answer.^.^

Comment: It did not. But as I'm not as close to completion as I originally thought, I've put off this part. I did get some advice on using the KeyTool app on the Xamarin Community. I assume that's the problem area.

Comment: problem not solved. I believe it's entirely due to something related to creating the keystore. The error only *seems* to happen if I include signing the app. Even if I create an entirely new app, create an entirely new keystore, etc and get the error. I just put whatever I want in the create keystore dialog, right? Or....?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create A Release Version
2. Click on Archive
3. Click on Distribute
4. Add New or Select a Keystore
   (this was probably my problem.)
5. Save As
   That's it.

One note: I checked MultiDex. And while that didn't create any build or other errors when I installed it on my phone, the app starts and then immediately shuts down. So I unchecked MultiDex. (ProGuard was checked).

(Note: I got help from Microsoft for this).